# Snowflake ODBC connectivity setup for SSAS tabular

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, ssas

I am trying to use the ODBC driver supplied by Snowflake to create a connection within SSAS (Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services) Tabular.  The ODBC connection checks out ok,  even processing a table within the model, sourced from snowflake, however, when trying to deploy the model, I get an error.

processing of snowflake source table -- success

[image]

attempting to deploy project via VS2017 - ODBC failure

[image]

ODBC Setup in VS, tried both "Windows" and "Database"

[image]

ODBC Setup in VS, Database Username/pwd

[image]

Am I missing any credential connection string properties (that seem to be optional)?

Answer (score 0):

the ODBC drivers need  to be set up on the server as well. Once done, connectivity checked out OK.